# How to load base64 image string into image slider in react native?

Tags: image, sqlite, react-native, base64

I am using a pre populated sqlite db with images stored in as BLOB data type..

Now I want to retrieve images and show in Image SliderBox in react native but somehow not able to do it..
I have used SliderBox from react-native-image-slider-box;

Below is my code

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      courtimages: [],
    }
  }
 getCourtImages (court_name){
    var that = this;
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT Image_Value FROM court_images where Court_Name= "Allahabad"', [], (tx, results) => {
        var len = results.rows.length;       
        if (len > 0) {
          let rowallimages = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var base64Icon = 'data:image/png;base64,results.rows.item(i)'; //not working
            rowallimages.push(base64Icon);
          }
          this.setState({ courtimages: rowallimages })
        }
      });
    });
  }

<SliderBox
          images={this.state.courtimages}
          sliderBoxHeight={400}
          dotColor="#FFEE58"
          inactiveDotColor="#90A4AE"
          autoplay
          circleLoop
          resizeMethod={'resize'}
          resizeMode={'cover'}
          ImageComponentStyle={{ borderRadius: 15, width: '100%'}}
        />
```

How to display BLOB images from slqlite db into slider box react native ???
Do help as I am new in React Native developemnt....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function should look like below,

```
getCourtImages (court_name){
    var that = this;
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT Image_Value FROM court_images where Court_Name= "Allahabad"', [], (tx, results) => {
        var len = results.rows.length;       
        if (len > 0) {
          let rowallimages = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var base64Icon = `data:image/png;base64,${results.rows.item(i)}`; //not working
            rowallimages.push(base64Icon);
          }
          this.setState({ courtimages: rowallimages })
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Main change is

```
var base64Icon = `data:image/png;base64,${results.rows.item(i)}`; //not working
```